# Time scale when measuring total activity from radioactive sample

Tags: experimental-physics, radioactivity

I have measured the total activity from a radioactive sample during an experiment by counting the number of decays happening in 3 seconds intervals. I got data as:

Time bin: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 
Count number: 307 294 257 246 250 216 186 169 ...

Now I want to curve fit an exponential $ae^{bt}$ to the data to determine $b$ as the decay constant. But since I have measured during intervals of 3 seconds, how should I convert/scale this data to get a proper estimate of the decay constant that has units s$^{-1}$?

Comment: are all the time intervals continuous, or did you pause between time intervals, and if so for how long did you pause?

Comment: They are all continous.